# Adding border to GridBagLayout rows

Tags: java, awt

I have a condition where, when ever i create a new row in GridBagLayout, then i have to add an bottom border to that row. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use [JSeparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html)

2) set/remove [Border](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for JComponent at last line

Comment: +1 It's not obvious from the tutorial, but a `MatteBorder` with zero insets on three side appears as a line.

Comment: thanks, you are right, basically Border can split to 4 prieces